# apt says there are no new upgrades to firefox 27

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Firefox 27.0. `apt-get install firefox` says it is already the latest version. [I know it is not true](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/web/firefox).

I have `precise`, `precise-backports`, `precise-security` and `precise-updates` on my `sources.list` ([full contents here](http://pastebin.com/KECwLcyU)).

I performed (apparently successfuly) and `apt-get update` and still the result is the same. I was able to install a new pakage (`guake`) so `apt` is talking to the internet just fine.

`apt-get upgrade` says "0 packages updated, 0 new installed, 0 to be removed, 0 not-updated".

Result of `apt-cache policy firefox`:

```
firefox:
  Instalado: 27.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidato: 27.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 27.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.0+build1-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Not a great answer, but at the bottom of the [package's page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/web/firefox#pdownload), it does have download links.. you can download the deb files and install those. Have you tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @Wilf Yeah, I don't want to install the `.deb` because IIRC it won't provide package updating, that's what I want, not to update to *this specific version*, but *always to the latest possible to this distro*.

Comment: Also, I tried `apt-get upgrade`, didn't work.

Comment: @chaskes I don't know what pinning or holding is. This is not my computer and I don't know how to check it.

Comment: I can see now that's not the problem here from apt-cache policy

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy: Just to verify, there aren't any warnings printed when you run `sudo apt-get update`, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two posibilities:

1. Brazil mirror is way behind

   I can assure is not:

   ```
   ➜  ~  apt-cache policy firefox
   firefox:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
     Version table:
        31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
           500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
   ```
2. There's a proxy that isn't working properly.

In the second case, you may have to ask the network administrator to fix it, bypass the proxy (using https or disabling it totally), or changing to other mirror removing the `br` part of your mirror list.